# SQL Server engine or stand-alone

Tags: sql-server-express

I begin release my applications in the city. I have a question, :

Which is better and why, for a local target system database ?

SQL Server Engine or for ex. SQL Server Express Edition ?

Comment: Not clear - SQL Server Express is also a SQL **Server** (should be installed on a **server machine** and used by multiple clients)

Comment: You will need to provide much more information about how your application will use the database before you can get any opinions. Also, questions soliciting opinions does not fit the SO Q&A format; read the FAQ.

Comment: Then For a Local Target System I should install Only Engine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your needs, the SQL Express doesn't support the SQL server engine to start with the MSSQL Server.

I'll Explain a bit, If you have SQL express 2008 or 2012 you cant run the SQL jobs for example the Automatic backup, cleanup or any other job that you would like to run on the SQL server automatically.

- The SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Database Size Limit Increased to 10GB, if you have bigger then 10GB database then you need to think of having the SQL server enterprise or web edition.
- SQL Server 2008 R2 Express is still limited to 1 CPU and 1 GB or RAM.
- Mirroring is not supported on SQL Express, and you cant have the SQL Server Profiler.

If you think you need more then 10GB database and more then 1CPU parallelism with SQL scheduler jobs then you should consider moving to SQL server enterprise edition or Web edition.

Regards,
Gabriel